# Android Studio - Rendering Problems

Tags: android, android-studio, view, android-custom-view

Okay, I belive answer is simple, but I am just advanced Android **user**, and hard-core newbie for Android Studio and programing, but I wish to learn.

When I start new project in Android Studio, (min sdk 8, blank activity) I get to resources files in /res/layout -- activity_main.xml and content_main.xml

If I change a theme for content_main, everything is ok, but if I change a theme for activity_main, I have a "Rendering Problems". It is happening just on begining, without any modifications, except changing a theme for activity_main.

This is a full output of "Rendering Problems":

> Rendering Problems Missing styles. Is the correct theme chosen for this layout?  Use the Theme combo box above the layout to choose a different layout, or fix the theme style references.  NOTE: One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes. These are required in most layouts.  Or: Automatically add all missing attributes   The following classes could not be instantiated:- android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>   - android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>   - android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton (Open Class, Show Exception, Clear Cache)
>    Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE  Exception Details java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.   at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:34)   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:178)   at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.(CoordinatorLayout.java:172)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394) Copy stack to clipboard  Failed to find style 'toolbarStyle' in current theme (3 similar errors not shown) Failed to convert ?attr/colorPrimary into a drawable (Details)

This is my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

}
}

This is my activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Both files are default.

Application hello world is compiled withouth errors, installed on phone and working. I understand this is only rendering problem in edit mode. Can someone help to hard-core newbie and tell me where exactly should to put, and how

```
View.isInEditMode()
```

Or maybe I should use, but how, and where

```
if (!isInEditMode())
```

Thanks in advance.